# Compare two timeseries, how to find mapping positions?

Tags: math, statistics, time-series, correlation

Let's assume two ***similar*** timeseries like below. Both are similar and never equal. E.g. the length can be different and similar parts can be between non-similar parts. I've tried to indicate the similarity by black arrows.

I'm not a mathematician and so I'm questioning if is there an approximately (or perfect) fast way to  find a mapping table between them? I've digged into dynamic time warping but at this point I'm thinking that *dtw* is not what I'm looking for (not sure).

The mapping table good be like

```
Sequence Location_Timeseries_0 Location_Timeseries_1 Length
0        LTO_0                 LT1_0                 N
1        LTO_1                 LT1_1                 M
...
```

Can someone put me into the right direction?

[image]

Comment: please fix sp.  *similar* , not "simmilar "

Comment: not a native eng. speaker

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you say/show, DTW is perfect

See the bottom right of http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/sampleslides2.jpg

or the right of http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/sampleslides3.jpg

Comment: I've compiled your code and it's really fast. But the output of UCR_DTW.cpp is one location. What about the other locations the timeseries' are similar (mapping mentioned above)? Can I get it somehow out of your code?

Comment: On SO, we usually prefer that you include the relevant code here.  The only actual useful part of your answer is that "DTW is perfect".

Comment: here'e the page with code mentioned by eamonn: http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/UCRsuite.html